# Bottled coconut oil

Tags: oil, coconut, heat

I order coconut oil and it is bottled. In the room temperature, it is solid, so I cannot reach the contents of the bottle. Is there a way, how to get that oil? I don't want to spoil it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the bottle in a hot water bath, with tepid water at about 100 F (38 C), and it will melt so you can pour it.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the kind of bottle. If it is wide-mouth, like a milk bottle, you can use either an ice cream spoon (its bowl is as large as a teaspoon, but the handle is ca. 20 cm long), or a warmish silicone brush. The second method is also recommended for coconut oil in jars when you need to reapply very little fat to a hot griddle (or a more specialized version like a waffle maker) after each item.

If it is close-mouth, SAJ's advice applies. Oils don't start to lose quality until they get to very high temperatures, and coconut oil melts long before that. You won't be spoiling it by melting.

Answer (score 0):

Set the jar in warm water or in the sun for a minute or two. The heat should soften it and make it accessible.